# html, css - how to use display: inline-block

Tags: html, css, dom

Why are the first three elements of second line not aligned? and how do i fix it?
I can fix it using float but is there any other way to fix it.[image]

```
display: inline-block;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yeqmpp5q/

Comment: inline-flex? http://jsfiddle.net/Leo_the_lion/yeqmpp5q/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` at `.floating`.

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjxmdgj6/)